# XLWings data link warning not caught by display_alerts

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I'm trying to write a script to do some basic daily processing on an excel workbook.  The workbook has several data links to pull data from outside, which when the book is opened prompt to be updated.  I want to automatically update them, ignore any that cannot be updated, and run the analysis.  My code to open the book right now is:

```
import xlwings as xw

the_app = xw.App()
the_app.display_alerts = False
book = xw.Book(r'FULL_FILE_PATH')
sheet = book.sheets[1]
print sheet['B1'].value
...
```

it opens the file, and once I manually handle the popups runs fine.  I've also tried not creating an app instance and just opening the book, which behaves the same as far as I can tell.

Comment: https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/562